# ElasticSearch NEST simple Terms query requires .keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I am trying to retrieve a single document with a secific name (exactly that name) using NEST 7.5.1 (.NET Core 3.1):

```
var queryByTerm = client.Search<SomeDto>(s =>s.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.NameField, "example name")));
```

But it does not return any documents (the call succeeds).

The actual query being sent (as seen in `DebugInformation` with `.EnableDebugMode` on client's `ConnectionSettings`):

```
{"query":{"term":{"nameField":{"value":"example name"}}}}
```

But it only works (in Kibana) when I add `.keyword` fo the `nameField`:

```
{"query":{"term":{"nameField.keyword":{"value":"example name"}}}}
```

Do I somehow have to force NEST to use `nameField.keyword` instead of `nameField`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `.Suffix()` extension method. [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/property-inference.html#property-inference).

```
var queryByTerm = client.Search<SomeDto>(s =>s.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.NameField.Suffix("keyword"), "example name")));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why do I have to add this?

Comment: You didn't share your index mapping, but I'm assuming field `NameField` is of type text which is being analyzed during indexing process which won't work well when you want to search document with the exact value. By default, elasticsearch creates two fields for string values, one of type text (`NameField`) and another one of type keyword (`NameField.keyword`) which is not being analyzed and allows you to look for exact values. You can read more about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html).